# Проблема с добавлением видео на сайт из вк

Tags: html, iframe

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
<iframe src="https://vk.com/video-145734245_456239021" width="607" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<iframe src="//vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=-145734245&id=456239021&hash=9873beaa75c6af9e&hd=2" width="853" height="480" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]